# creating a command to load a shell script from command line

Tags: command-line, scripts

Right now when I want to run a specific program, I perform the following task:

```
cd ~/Downloads
~/Downloads$ cd RubyMine-6.3.3
~/Downloads/RubyMine-6.3.3$ cd bin
./rubymine.sh
```

Instead of doing all that, I would like to say "mine" from the command line and have it load as it does above.

```
$ echo $PATH
$ cd ~/bin
$ ln -s /home/myuser/Downloads/RubyMine-6.3.3/bin/rubymine.sh ~/bin
$ cd ~/bin && ls -l | grep rubymine.sh
rubymine.sh -> /home/myuser/Downloads/RubyMine-6.3.3/bin/rubymine.sh
$ cd ~/bin && ./rubymine.sh
```

This is the part I want to convert into a command: "cd ~/bin && ./rubymine.sh". Any idea how?

Comment: Just rename it to "mine" and type "mine" at the prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/bin` is (if it exists) added to your path automagically. All you need to do here is rename your link to `mine`.

Answer (score 0):

run the following command

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
~/bin/rubymine.sh' | sudo tee /usr/bin/mine && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/mine
```

but, if I'm not mistaken, you want the first group of commands to run and that can be done simply like this:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
~/Downloads/RubyMine-6.3.3/bin/rubymine.sh' | sudo tee /usr/bin/mine && chmod +x /usr/bin/mine
```

In both cases, run the command

```
mine
```

to execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.` tricks, with the suggestion of other answers.

For example:

`chmod +x rubymine.sh`, assuming you have already gone to the path to file then run the file with any one of these command:

```
sh rubymine.sh

./rubymine.sh

. rubymine.sh
```